# FormsModule: How to force to change the values?

Tags: angular

I am trying to force to change the values of my form (`FormsModule`).

In my function I have tried it with

```
@ViewChild('customForm', {static: true}) customForm: NgForm;

myFunction() {
   this.customForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe();
}
```

but I get the error:

> ERROR TypeError: generatorOrNext is not a function

How can I make my function update the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Angular Docs on [**`valueChanges`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControlDirective#valueChanges):

> Returns a multicasting observable of value changes for the control that emits every time **the value of the control changes in the UI or programmatically**. If the control is not present, null is returned.

You're not trying to change the value by using this. You're trying to listen to changes in the values of the control.

You should ideally be using some other methods like [**`updateModel`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#updatemodel)(to just set a value of one `NgControl`) or [**`setValue`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#setvalue)(to set the value of the whole `FormGroup`) instead. Calling these methods on `this.customForm` will force the form to change it's values.

### UPDATE

`this.customForm.form` would be an instance of [**`FormGroup`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup). So you could ideally also use methods like [**`setValue`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) or [**`patchValue`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#patchValue) on it to update the form and trigger a change.

Comment: Well explained answer buddy, you are a GEM if Angular Forms ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have realized that `subscribe()` needs a function as parameter. So I have just tried it that way and it works:

```
this.customForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => null );
```